# C++ thread error: no type named ‘type’ MINGW

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently doing a project for my operational systems class and I have to make a program to find prime numbers to run in threads.

So I did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#define THREADNUMBER 100
using namespace std;


int CONTADOR = 0;
int CONTADORTHREADEXECUTADA = 0;
int primeRange(int v1, int v2) {
int a, limit;                        
bool isprime;

for (int i = v1; i <= v2; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0) {
        isprime = true;
        limit = i / 2;
        if(i == 1) isprime =false;


        limit = (int)sqrt(i); //General case

        for(a=2; a <= limit; a++){
            if(i % i == 0 && i != 2){
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) {
            CONTADOR++;
        }

    }
}
CONTADORTHREADEXECUTADA++;
return 1;
} 
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ] ) {
int number1 =  atoi(argv[1]);
int number2 = atoi(argv[2]);
int dif = number2-number1;
thread** vec = new thread*[THREADNUMBER];
cout<< "criando threads" <<endl;
int contadorthread = 0;
if (dif <= THREADNUMBER) {
    for(int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
        thread* t = new thread(primeRange(i,i));
        vec[contadorthread] = t; 
        contadorthread++;
    }
} else {
    int c = dif / THREADNUMBER;

    for(int i = number1; i <= number2; i+=(c+1)) {
        if (contadorthread==THREADNUMBER-1) {
            thread* t = new thread(primeRange(i,number2));
            vec[contadorthread] = t; 
            contadorthread++;
            break;
        }
        thread* t = new thread(primeRange(i,i+c));
        vec[contadorthread] = t; 
        contadorthread++;

    }
cout<<contadorthread << " threads criadas"<<endl;
cout<<"inicializando threads" <<endl;

while (CONTADORTHREADEXECUTADA < contadorthread) {
    cout<<contadorthread - CONTADORTHREADEXECUTADA << endl;
}
cout<< CONTADOR << "primos encontrados" <<endl;
} 
}
```

But everytime I try to compile on 64 windows GCC I get this error message saying that there is not type named 'type'

I compile with this

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -pthread codigo.cpp -o exe -Wall
```

What can I do? 
I already downloaded the version of mingw they say is thread safe.

Comment: Please, add **exact error message** into the question post. If the error message contain the line number, show that line in your code.

Comment: BTW you are leaking thread objects. Why are you using all those `new` and naked pointers? Just put plain `std::thread` objects straight into an `std::vector`.

Comment: Please show exactly what build of mingw-w64 you are using (I presume you are actually using mingw-w64 and not mingw). Some of them do not actually have std thread support out-of-the-box

Comment: @MatteoItalia IMO it would be preferable to use a higher level abstraction over `std::thread`, e.g. `packaged_task` or `async`

Comment: This message usually means you are trying to instantiate a template incorrectly. (It's not a good error message but that's how templates work right now). The template in your case is the std::thread constructor.

Comment: @M.M of course, but that's going for style points, here we have a straight memory leak (and probably some confusion about `new` in first place) to fix first. 

Comment: I used all this configuration cause my teacher asked for them. I actually got the answer yesterday and it was just like @code707 answered here, but I was very busy doing my program so couldn't come here to close the topic. But thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
thread* t = new thread(primeRange(i,i));
```

call function primeRange and pass result(int) to thread constructor which is obviously not the way to call. Instead use:

```
thread* t = new thread(primeRange, i, i);
```

It will pass function pointer as well as arguments to thread constructor.

Comment: Thanks! I actually got the answer from a friend, but was very busy with the job. But it hoped, thank you again.